# How can i change the DateTime format to fit the string i build?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I have **this loop** :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateTime.Count; i++)
{
    link = "test" + dateTime[i].Year + dateTime[i].Month
              + dateTime[i].Day + dateTime[i].TimeOfDay.Hours
              + dateTime[i].TimeOfDay.Minutes
              + "text1" + infraredorvisual;
    WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
    string filePath = Path.Combine(satimagesdir, "SatImage" + i + ".GIF");

    client1.DownloadFile(link, filePath);
    client1.Dispose();
}
```

Inside the List dateTime i have some items the first one look like this: [0] = {12/01/2015 08:00:00}

The string i build the link variable i'm getting now is:

```
texthttp://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201511280&text1
```

But the time format is wrong.
I should get in link this string:

http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501120330&ir=True

Both strings are only examples.

In the first one the time is 9 digits: year = 2015 then day 1/12 and time 80 the time 80 meaning eight.

But the format of the date and time should be like in the second example:

```
year = 2015 day = 01/12 and time 0330 .... 201501120330
```

How can i build the link variable with the right time and date formats like in the second example ?

Comment: You can format `DateTime` by calling `ToString` with the appropriate format, in your case `.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")` I think

Comment: One improvement would be to initialize `WebClient` before the loop and dispose it after the loop if you don't plan to download files in parallel. Also, take a look at `string.Format`. It can make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string result = dateTime[i].ToString("yyyyddMMHHmm");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx